# Can you play a wild card on an existing Canasta to go out?

Tags: canasta

Canasta. Can you play a wild card on an existing Canasta to go out?

Comment: It looks like you may have created 2 separate accounts. If this is the case, you can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge them. You can always comment on your own questions if you need further clarification; or if you have a separate question just ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

You can add to existing melds in general; whether going out or not. This includes adding a wild to an existing Canasta.

> A player may add additional cards to a meld by his side, provided that the melds remain valid (having no more than three wild cards).

Note that if you add a wild to a natural Canasta, it will become a mixed Canasta.

> Additional cards may be added to a canasta to score their point values, but these do not affect the bonus - except that a wild card added to a natural canasta reduces it to a mixed canasta (and a black card replaces the red card that was previously on top).